# MongoDB Update returns true, but not reflected in DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm sending an update to mongo (via a javascript function). I am simply adding a new boolean field to an existing document which has an existing field of emailAddress.

the result comes back as:

{"ok":true,"n":1,"updatedExisting":true}

However, when I check the db directly, it has not actually been updated.

This is the actual code. Anyone know why this might not be working? it is as though the update hasn't been committed or is in some sort of cache.

```
var updateEmail = function (address, flagVal, dbName, callback) {

  var newVal = (flagVal === 'true');  
  var newField = {"Bounced" : newVal };
  //collection is global variable in file
  collection.update({"emailAddress":address}, 
                                {$set : newField }, 
                                {upsert:false, multi:false, writeConcern: {w:"marjority"}},
                                function (err, result) { 
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    callback(null);
  });
  callback(null);

}
```

Comment: looks like you should change this `upsert:false` to `upsert:true`

Comment: @yogesh The returned message says `"updatedExisting":true`, so this should not make a difference in this case.

Comment: I agree with @Philipp that it shouldn't make a difference. The record that is being updated does exist already in some cases. But just in case, I tried changing it to upsert:true and it still didn't work.

Comment: `writeConcern: {w:"marjority"}`? Shouldn't that be [**`writeConcern: {w:"majority"}`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.0/#w-majority)?

Comment: how are you calling your function?

Comment: @chridam - yes you're correct -- that was a copy/paste error from prior to fixing it.  The call is returning as successful regardless though

Comment: @Michael - I'm calling it from my request handler. 
I've found the error -- the call 
    `var newVal = (flagVal === 'true');`
is always evaluating to false.  It turns out that the call is already passing in a boolean rather than a String as I though.
Thanks everyone!

Comment: @BobAleena That is why I was asking

Comment: @Michael - thanks! wouldn't have caught it otherwise!